# Can't run rspec on 64 bit Win 7

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I installed rspec without any issue. However, when I run the command `rspec`, I got the following error. Anyone can help?

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]

C:\>rspec
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/spec (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

C:\>gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.9)
actionpack (3.2.9)
activemodel (3.2.9)
activerecord (3.2.9)
activeresource (3.2.9)
activesupport (3.2.9)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2)
awesome_print (1.1.0)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.2)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
domain_name (0.5.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
json (1.7.5, 1.5.4)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.4.4)
mechanize (2.5.1)
mechanize-progressbar (0.2.0)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.3.7)
net-http-digest_auth (1.2.1)
net-http-persistent (2.8)
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
ocra (1.3.0)
pik (0.2.8)
polyglot (0.3.3)
progressbar (0.12.0)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.9)
railties (3.2.9)
rake (10.0.2, 0.9.2.2)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
rspec (2.12.0)
rspec-core (2.12.1)
rspec-expectations (2.12.0)
rspec-mocks (2.12.0)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10, 0.11.30.pre3)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta14)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
sass (3.2.3)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
shoes (3.0.1)
sprockets (2.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.6 x86-mingw32)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
tiny_tds (0.5.1 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
unf (0.0.5)
unf_ext (0.0.5 x86-mingw32)
webrobots (0.0.13)
wxruby-ruby19 (2.0.1 x86-mingw32)

C:\>
```

---

Edit:

As David pointed out, I don't have `spec` folder under c:\. After create that folder, everything seems just fine. I'm sorry for this silly question. I'm totally new to rspec. Thank you all!

```
C:\>mkdir spec

C:\>rspec
No examples found.


Finished in 0 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

C:\>
```

Comment: Do you have a file or path with a space in its name? "c:/spec <something>"?

Comment: Oh, I don't have a `spec` folder under c:\. After I create one, it seems everything is fine. See my edit. Thank you David!

Comment: Why are you on the root of your drive?

Comment: My terminal happens to at the root of the C drive before I start to test the `rspec` command. No specific reason. Thank you David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rspec` command is supposed to be run in the directory context of a project, not arbitrarily at the root of your drive. It's complaining because it can't find a specific `spec` folder to execute against. Creating one at the root seems more than a bit peculiar.

Each project should have its own `spec` directory and the `rspec` command should be executed from the parent of that directory.